Common library custom exception issue
I am creating a common library for use in my two other repositories, so I can import this library into both repos. However, I have encountered an issue.
One repo uses an exception called RecruitException, and the other uses an exception called DeveloperException. I have a file in the library that is used by both repos, and I want to throw an exception using the exception name relevant to the repo from which it is called.
How can I configure this?
Thank you in advance.
I searched this and I got some solutions like to pass the exception name in the parameters.
But I don't want to do this as I have 20 common files and each file contains atleast 10 methods, so I am finding the best generic way to achieve my goal.

The usual method of doing this is to have a config.py (or similar) that has definitions specific to that repo.  Do DevException = DeveloperException or DevException = RecruitException as needed.

Thank you replying but how to configure that which repo is calling the exception so that I can use exception defined in that repo

You can't know who is calling you.  There will need to be SOME code in each repo to tell your package which exception it should use.
